# Scala: Recursively building all paths in a graph?

Tags: scala, recursion, graph

Trying to build all existing paths for an udirected graph defined as a map of edges using the following algorithm:

```
Start: with a given vertice A 
Find an edge (X.A, X.B) or (X.B, X.A), add this edge to path if not already in path
Find all edges Ys for which either (Y.C, Y.B) or (Y.B, Y.C) is true 
For each Ys: A=B, goto Start
```

Providing edges are defined as the following map, where keys are tuples consisting of two vertices:

```
    val edges = Map(
      ("n1", "n2") -> "n1n2",
      ("n1", "n3") -> "n1n3",
      ("n3", "n4") -> "n3n4",
      ("n5", "n1") -> "n5n1",
      ("n5", "n4") -> "n5n4")
```

As an output I need to get a list of ALL pathes where each path is a list of adjecent edges like this:

```
  val allPaths = List(
    List(("n1", "n2") -> "n1n2"),
    List(("n1", "n3") -> "n1n3", ("n3", "n4") -> "n3n4"),
    List(("n5", "n1") -> "n5n1"),
    List(("n5", "n4") -> "n5n4"),
    List(("n2", "n1") -> "n1n2", ("n1", "n3") -> "n1n3", ("n3", "n4") -> "n3n4", ("n5", "n4") -> "n5n4"))
    //...
    //... more pathes to go
}
```

Note: Edge XY = (x,y) -> "xy" and  YX = (y,x) -> "yx" exist as one instance only, either as XY or YX

So far I have managed to implement code that duplicates edges in the path, which is wrong and I can not find the error:

```
object Graph2 {
  type Vertice = String
  type Edge = ((String, String), String)
  type Path = List[((String, String), String)]

  val edges = Map(
    //(("v1", "v2") , "v1v2"),
    (("v1", "v3") , "v1v3"),
    (("v3", "v4") , "v3v4")
    //(("v5", "v1") , "v5v1"),
    //(("v5", "v4") , "v5v4")
    )

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val processedVerticies: Map[Vertice, Vertice] = Map()
    val processedEdges: Map[(Vertice, Vertice), (Vertice, Vertice)] = Map()
    val path: Path = List()
    println(buildPath(path, "v1", processedVerticies, processedEdges))

  }

  /**
   * Builds path from connected by edges vertices starting from given vertice
   * Input: map of edges
   * Output: list of connected edges like:
   List(("n1", "n2") -> "n1n2"),
    List(("n1", "n3") -> "n1n3", ("n3", "n4") -> "n3n4"),
    List(("n5", "n1") -> "n5n1"),
    List(("n5", "n4") -> "n5n4"),
    List(("n2", "n1") -> "n1n2", ("n1", "n3") -> "n1n3", ("n3", "n4") -> "n3n4", ("n5", "n4") -> "n5n4"))
   */
  def buildPath(path: Path,
    vertice: Vertice,
    processedVerticies: Map[Vertice, Vertice],
    processedEdges: Map[(Vertice, Vertice), (Vertice, Vertice)]): List[Path] = {
    println("V: " + vertice + " VM:  " + processedVerticies + " EM: " + processedEdges)
    if (!processedVerticies.contains(vertice)) {
      val edges = children(vertice)
      println("Edges: " + edges)
      val x = edges.map(edge => {
        if (!processedEdges.contains(edge._1)) {
          addToPath(vertice, processedVerticies.++(Map(vertice -> vertice)), processedEdges, path, edge)
        } else {
          println("ALready have edge: "+edge+" Return path:"+path)
          path
        }
      })
      val y = x.toList
      y
    } else {
      List(path)
    }
  }

  def addToPath(
    vertice: Vertice,
    processedVerticies: Map[Vertice, Vertice],
    processedEdges: Map[(Vertice, Vertice), (Vertice, Vertice)],
    path: Path,
    edge: Edge): Path = {

    val newPath: Path = path ::: List(edge)
    val key = edge._1
    val nextVertice = neighbor(vertice, key)

    val x = buildPath (newPath, 
             nextVertice, 
             processedVerticies, 
             processedEdges ++ (Map((vertice, nextVertice) -> (vertice, nextVertice)))
          ).flatten // need define buidPath type 
    x
  }

  def children(vertice: Vertice) = {
    edges.filter(p => (p._1)._1 == vertice || (p._1)._2 == vertice)
  }

  def containsPair(x: (Vertice, Vertice), m: Map[(Vertice, Vertice), (Vertice, Vertice)]): Boolean = {
    m.contains((x._1, x._2)) || m.contains((x._2, x._1))
  }

  def neighbor(vertice: String, key: (String, String)): String = key match {
    case (`vertice`, x) => x
    case (x, `vertice`) => x
  }

}
```

Running this results in:

```
List(List(((v1,v3),v1v3), ((v1,v3),v1v3), ((v3,v4),v3v4)))
```

Why is that?

Comment: so, uhm - [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination)?

Comment: If you want to stick to recursion, a [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth_first_search) should do the job. Here's a post on [MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/18603/finding-all-paths-on-undirected-graph) talking about it. Now, go ahead and implement it! If you're stuck anywhere, post here as an edit.